# I want to show note onclick of button only if I uncheck checkbox using jquery

Tags: jquery

Please check above link.There is a note "*Please agree to the Privacy Policy and Disclaimer" I want to show this note onclick of button but only if I have checked "I have read and agree to the Privacy Policy and Disclaimer" this checkbox.At first I want to hide that note.I want to show that note onclick of button only when I have not checked that checkbox.Please advise...

Here is my code.

```
    $('#newprivacy').css('color','#ff0000');
 $('#newprivacy').hide();
 $('#btnContinue').click(function(e) { 
if(!document.getElementById('privacypolicy').checked) { 
// checkbox not checked e.preventDefault(); $('#newprivacy').show(); } else { 
$('#AccountSettingsForm').submit(); 
} });
 $('#privacypolicy').click(function(){ 
if ($('#privacypolicy').is(":checked")) {
 $('#newprivacy').hide();

     } });   }
```

Its not working on chrome and IE why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The majority of the functionality seems to be there, you just need to disable the button again if they uncheck the checkbox after checking it. I've made a few changes to your code below, namely:

1. Using the `change` event on the checkbox rather than the `click` event, this way it will still fire if they use their keyboard to change its state.
2. Using `this` to refer to the checkbox in the event handler function, rather than selecting it again, and accessing the `checked` property directly on the element, rather than using the jQuery `.is()` function.
3. Using the `.prop()` function rather than the `.attr()` function to modify the `disabled` property of the button.

jQuery code:

```
$("#btnContinue").prop("disabled", true);
$('#newprivacy').css('color', '#ff0000');
$('#privacypolicy').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#newprivacy').hide();
        $("#btnContinue").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
        $('#newprivacy').show();
        $('#btnContinue').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

I'm assuming the above code is either included in a `$(document).ready()` call or located at the end of the page, so that the elements are available when the code executes.

Note that the effects of the first two lines could also be achieved using HTML, saving the need to hide and color them using jQuery or JavaScript code.

And, if you really want to completely replace that logic with a `click` event handler on the button, this should do it:

```
$('#btnContinue').click(function(e) {
    if(!document.getElementById('privacypolicy').checked) {
        // checkbox not checked
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#newprivacy').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#AccountSettingsForm').submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you its working for me.But when I click on button without checking that checkbox it should not go to next page.

Comment: Please reply.I dont want show next page unless I check that checkbox.

Comment: @Rashmi The code I posted at the end of my answer will only post the form if the checkbox is checked, so I'm not really sure what issues you're having with it. Is the link provided in your question the current version of the code that's giving you issues?

Comment: @Rashmi Edited to prevent the default behaviour of the click event if the checkbox is unchecked; if that solves the issue you can do away with the `else` part entirely. When I tested earlier clicking on the image (`#btnContinue`) wasn't submitting the form at all, so I assumed you'd need to programmatically submit it.

Comment: hiii I have used this code its working properly but only on firefox after clicking on continue button it redirects to next page but its not redirecting to next page on chrome and IE why?

Comment: @Rash What's the exact code you're using? A pastebin or jsFiddle (even if it doesn't work) just so I can see it would be great.

Comment: I have used  $('#newprivacy').css('color','#ff0000');
 $('#newprivacy').hide();

$('#btnContinue').click(function(e) {
    if(!document.getElementById('privacypolicy').checked) {
        // checkbox not checked
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#newprivacy').show();
    }
 
 
    else  {
        $('#AccountSettingsForm').submit();
  
    }
 
});
 $('#privacypolicy').click(function(){
  if ($('#privacypolicy').is(":checked")) {
  
  $('#newprivacy').hide(); 
    }
}); 
}

Comment: @Rash Is there a site where I can see the code (not) working?

Comment: please check above link on chrome you will find my problem

Comment: @ Anthony Grist plz check link from question

Answer (score 1):

hide the div when document is ready first....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#newprivacy').hide();
});
```

and then put your codes there...
i think that will work....

Answer (score 1):

I think you should see the w3schools documentation on the use of the 'hidden' attribute.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

And then you can always use jquery to add and remove this attribute. Or change it's values.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#btnContinue').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($('#privacypolicy').is(":checked")) {

        //either submit form or return true
        $('#AccountSettingsForm').submit();
    }
    else {

        $('#newprivacy').show();

        return false;
    }


});
```

then on clicking the checkbox you can remove the privacy policy.

Comment: Its working for me but I want to show that note onclick of button only when I have not checked that checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#newprivacy').hide();
 $("#btnContinue").attr("disabled", "disabled");
 $('#newprivacy').css('color','#ff0000');
 $('#privacypolicy').click(function(){
 if ($('#privacypolicy').is(":checked")) {
    $("#btnContinue").removeAttr("disabled");
}
else 
{
    $('#newprivacy').show();
}
});})
```

Comment: `$('#privacypolicy')` returns a jQuery object, which doesn't have a `checked` property, so calling `$('#privacypolicy').checked` won't work.